# Correct selector to get span element in a table in Rust with scraper

Tags: web-scraping, css-selectors

I want to extract the value 0.45 in the span element. But I am not able to grep the span element. Is it possible to  give me the right selector? My selector doesn't work.

```rust
use scraper::{Selector, Html};
let parsed_html=Html::parse_document("<tr id='12345678'><td>...</td> <td>...</td> <td><span>0.45</span></td> </tr>");

let selector=Selector::parse("tr[id='12345678']:nth-child(3):nth-child(1)").unwrap();

let fragment=parsed_html
    .select(&selector)
    .next()
    .unwrap();
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with rust, your selector is just plain incorrect: [`nth-child` is a pseudo-class which filters elements based on their position amongst their sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child), so it has to be applied to the child, it's not a [combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference#combinators). Here your selector is trying to select the tr of id `12345678` which is simulatnously the 1st and 3rd child (of its parent).

Comment: IOW, the correct selector is probably `tr[id='12345678'] td:nth-child(3) span`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let selector=Selector::parse("tr#12345678 > td:nth-child(3) > span").unwrap();
```